# Can Two controllers of two different routes can share same service?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to reuse the same service across multiple controllers on two different routes. I set name of an object in service using first controller and change the route and try to fetch the same object in service using second controller nothing gets printed.

```
app.js(file):

   angular.module('sampleapp', ["ngRoute"]).

   config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
  .when('/',
   {
    templateUrl: 'src/loginform/loginform.html',
    controller: 'LoginFormController'
   })
  .when('/home',
   {
     templateUrl: 'src/home/home.html',
     controller: 'HomeController'
   })
}])

Service Code: 

angular.module('sampleapp').service("CommonService", [function() {
  const Names = [
    {Name: "Mounish", age: 27},
    {Name: "Chakradhari", age: 24},
    {Name: "Venkat", age: 28}
  ];

  this.data = {
    firstName: ''
  };

  this.printNames = function() {
    return Names;
  }

  this.setName = function(value) {
    this.data.firstName = value;
  }

  this.getName = function() {
    return this.data.firstName;
  }

}])

Login form (controller 1):

angular.module('sampleapp')
.controller('LoginFormController', ["$scope", "$location", "CommonService", function($scope, $location , CommonService) {
  $scope.username = "jamili";
  $scope.submitHandler = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Clicked");
    window.location.href = '/home';
  };

  CommonService.setName("Mounish");
  CommonService.getName();
}])

Home Page (Controller 2): 
angular.module('sampleapp')
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', "CommonService", function($scope, CommonService) {
    $scope.names = CommonService.printNames();
    console.log($scope.names);
    console.log(CommonService.getName());
}])
```

I am trying to reuse the same service across multiple controllers on two different routes. I set name of an object in service using first controller and change the route and try to fetch the same object in service using second controller nothing gets printed.

Comment: is there any errors

Comment: Maybe nothing gets printed because you don't stock your value somewhere. If you are trying to pass a value from one controller to another you can't do it on the fly, either you save your values or pass them as parameters in your route.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,angular services are intended to share data among multiple controllers and services.

Here, You are initializing your module multiple times. Angular module is a container for different parts of app, like controllers, services, directive etc.You should create your angular `module` once. If you create angular module multiple times, It will override previous module.

Here is a [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) for angular module.

You can follow [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/dJvtmOohRdVhgwAzq0ML?p=preview) approach to register your controllers and services.

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp',[])
sampleApp.service('CommonService',function(){
  //your processing logic 
});

sampleApp.controller('Controller_1',function($scope,CommonService){
  //write your code here
});

sampleApp.controller('Controller_2',function($scope,CommonService){
 //write your code here
});
```

I hope this would help you!!